# Python3: How to run localhost on background?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

This is my code:

```
import _thread 
import http.server
import socketserver

def func():
    PORT = 8002
    Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

    httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT),Handler)


    _thread.start_new_thread(httpd.serve_forever())

func()
```

I want to run this on the background, Is it possible.The above code is not working as expected it is working on the foreground.How can I make it on the Background?

I want this to test my downloader written in python.

```
.....

r=requests.get('http://localhost:8002/file.dat',stream=True)

with open('file.dat','wb')as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=(1*1024*1024):
        f.write(chunk)

......
```

And I can't use more than one processor because I am writing this code in pythonista in iOS which does not support the use of more than one process but supports the use of multithreading

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it's not working? If that HTTP server is running on your iDevice, are you sure the app does not become suspended?

Comment: @hsk I meant that it is working ,But not on an another thread,it is working on the Mainthread